# Group_CONCAT() retrieve information

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 3 tables, but i believe only 2 of them are needed for now. the tables are called

1: athlete
2: training_session
3: club

[image: training_session]
[image: club]

I want to for each country retrieve traning activities performed within the clubs in that country, the other activities are seperated by "," inside each list, no repeated  values exist

```
SELECT activity GROUP_CONCAT (DISTINCT activity ORDER BY activity 
SEPARATOR ',') as "test" FROM training_session group by activity
```

I expect it to be 2 rows returned, that is what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing all columns of your tables, but as an educated guess I think that you need the three tables here. You can start from the `training_sessions`, then join on `athletes` based on the `athlete_id`, and finally on `club` based on the `club_id`. Then you can aggregate by club country and use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)`, that you seem to already know about:

```
SELECT
    c.country,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ts.activity ORDER BY activity) activities
FROM training_session ts
INNER JOIN athlete a ON a.id = ts.athlete_id
INNER JOIN club c ON c.id = a.club_id
GROUP BY c.country
```

Comment: I get this error message. Something is wrong in your syntax nær 'DISTINCT ts.activity ORDER BY activity) activities
FROM training_session ts on line 3

Comment: @Lilly Group_concat is a function and there should not be a space between it and (